# Are there any Scala OAuth libraries that support OAuth 2.0?

Tags: scala, oauth, oauth-2.0, lift, scala-dispatch

I'm looking for both consumer and provider code. Dispatch and Lift's OAuth code both only target OAuth 1.0 right now.

Comment: Does it have to be Scala or can use you Java?

Comment: Could be Java but I feel like with many Java libraries I spend plenty of time jumping through hoops to make it halfway sane. I guess I'm just spoiled by Scala. ;-)

Comment: According to Play Framework: "Version 2 is simple enough to be implemented easily without library or helpers, so Play only provides support for OAuth 1.0." http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaOAuth

Answer (score 1):

It's **far** from a lib but maybe it can help as en example for you to write your own lib:

https://github.com/denibertovic/scala-oauth2